# Facebook canvas app not loading, scraper shows correct document

Tags: facebook, heroku, sinatra, facebook-canvas, koala

I've created a FB application, hosted on Heroku. The app is written in Ruby.

1. The app used to load correctly inside facebook iframe.
2. Now, if I open the app through `app.facebook.com/app_namespace`, an empty screen is shown. When I have enabled exception trace, it now shows as if the access_token for graph koala object is nil.
3. If I open Canvas URL, e.g. the "direct" URL everything works fine, but I have to first call direct authroization on facebook through "/auth/facebook".
4. The iframe now shows koala "Unsupported get method", but through debugging it is evident that access_token obtained from graph is nil.
5. Behavior is the same for generated test users as well as developer users.

Already tried:

1. I've tried to debug the Canvas URL through online FB debugger, and Scraper seems to see correct HTML.
2. Try to reauthorize the app, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Sinatra [uses rack-protection to set the `X-Frame_Options` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840613/how-do-i-get-sinatra-to-refrain-from-adding-the-x-frame-options-header/7841082#7841082). It looks like this is what is causing your problems.

You can disable it with this line in your application:

```
set :protection, :except => :frame_options
```

Comment: Matt, thanks. This could be problem with access_token. Now, the "standalone" version works well after I call "<app>/auth/facebook" and then I can use it. For the iframe version this does not help. Also, I have enabled show_exceptions and the problem is that inside iFrame access_token is not valid? 
I'm confused. :)

Comment: Matt, I'll accept the answer, this did help.
What's the syntax to :except multiple values, e.g. :frame_options and :http_origin?

Comment: @emirc use an array: `set :protection, :except => [:frame_options, :http_origin]` http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuring%20attack%20protection