# X-Frame-Options on torquebox-server

Tags: web, x-frame-options, torquebox

I'm struggling while getting a webpage running on my torquebox-server. The page itself is working fine, but to integrate this into another webiste I need to enable (or at least change them to another value) the X-Frame-options for the torquebox-server. I wasn' able to find something in the documentation, and there is also no part in the config file, which seems to be the correct place to change this.
Has someone already tried this or got this running on torquebox?
I would be very grateful, if someone could help me out..
Cheers Tim

Answer (score 1):

After some morge research I've found out, that this isn't solvable with torquebox, but I just need to change my application. The application is using sinatra as framework, which uses Rack:Protection as a security module. In this module the "sameorigin" option is set (thanks to grep ;) ). Sinatra offers the possibility to exclude options from modules, in this case it was `set :protection, :except => :frame_options`
(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840613/how-do-i-get-sinatra-to-refrain-from-adding-the-x-frame-options-header))

So, maybe this is helpful for someone, who's having the same problem